# How to use NDSolve to get relations between functions with parameter?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, nonlinear, coordinate-transformation

In this project I'm doing, one small part is to find out the relations between z and r. However, since everything is under another coordinate (with xi and eta). I do have the transformation(from cylindrical to bipolar):

```
r[η_, ξ_] = Sin[η]/(Cosh[ξ] - Cos[η]);
z[η_, ξ_] = Sinh[ξ]/(Cosh[ξ] - Cos[η]);
```

So, the differential equation is

```
dz/dr==f[η, ξ]
```

And I only know the range and initial condition for `ξ` and `η`.

How can I use NDSolve to find out `z[r]`? Or, can I actually use NDSolve?

Comment: Is `f` a given function?

Comment: Yes, f is a given function but the hard part is that this function is about eta and xi.

Comment: I tried this: Calculate Dz/D[eta], Dz/D[xi], Dr/D[eta], Dr/D[xi]. then, put them in this: (Dz/D[eta]+Dz/D[xi]*D[eta]/D[xi]) /(Dr/D[eta]+ Dr/D[xi]*D[eta]/D[xi])==f(eta,xi). However, mathematica give me alert: the D[eta]/D[xi]not clearly specified in the form f[eta,xi]. I changed f[eta,xi] into f[eta[xi],xi], but still, same alert is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z` is not a single-valued function of `r`, as can be seen from

```
r[η_, ξ_] := Sin[η]/(Cosh[ξ] - Cos[η]);
z[η_, ξ_] := Sinh[ξ]/(Cosh[ξ] - Cos[η]);
ParametricPlot[Evaluate@Table[{r[η, i], z[η, i]}, {i, -5, 5}], 
    {ξ, -5, 5}, {η, -5, 5}, FrameLabel -> {r, z}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, All}]
```

[image]

For every value of `r`, there are an infinite number of values of `z`.  To obtain a single curve, a relationship between `ξ` and `η` is required.

This is not a Mathematica shortcoming but instead reflects the nature of the mathematics.

**Addendum**

Based on the clarification of the question given in comments below, one might try obtaining `{η, ξ}` as a function of `{r, z}`,

```
Simplify[Solve[{r == Sin[η]/(Cosh[ξ] - Cos[η]), z == Sinh[ξ]/(Cosh[ξ] - Cos[η])}, 
    {ξ, η}][[2]] /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 0}]

(* {ξ -> Log[Sqrt[r^2 + (1 + z)^2]/Sqrt[r^2 + (-1 + z)^2]], 
    η -> ArcTan[(-1 + r^2 + z^2)/(Sqrt[r^2 + (-1 + z)^2] Sqrt[r^2 + (1 + z)^2]), 
    (2 r)/(Sqrt[r^2 + (-1 + z)^2] Sqrt[r^2 + (1 + z)^2])]} *)
```

and substituting this result into `f[η, ξ]` to obtain the ODE entirely as a function of `{r, z}`.

```
D[z[r], r] == f[η, ξ] /. % /. z -> z[r]
```

`NDSolve` probably can solve this ODE without difficulty.

Using `NDSolve` to solve all three equations in the question simultaneously as a differential-algebraic system also might work.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer. What you said is true, we do need a relation between ξ and η. However, if you read closely, It's given, but implicitly: you have Dz/Dr==f(ξ, η). And this will define a curve in the ξ-η plane, so, it also defines a curve in the r-z plane. But I want the this be solved in the r-z plane instead of the ξ-η plane.

Comment: Please provide f(ξ, η) in the question.

Comment: this f is a ratio of two partial derivatives of some phi with ξ and η, respectively. and I got the phi by a huge formula with an integral with another variable miu of a function A(miu) which I got from solving a difference equation....